# Quit and Re-join room

Tags: webrtc, simplewebrtc

I am making a video chat application using simplewebrtc. It is working fine with one call.After hanging up(`webrtc.leaveRoom()`) when I try to call again then it is not working.It is not executing    `webrtc.on('readyToCall', function() {
            console.log('Ready to call');
            webrtc.joinRoom(room);
        });`
So how can I ressolve this issue? Is there any issue with my old connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I made changes inside simplewebrtc. I changed the file 
`/node_modules/simplewebrtc/src/simplewebrtc.js`. I just remove comments from line `'force new connection': true`.(***I will never recommend this***).

Now this line looks like `socketio: { 'force new connection': true }` and it is working.

thanks.